# PHP/Laravel: Run function as long as something happend

Tags: php, laravel, file, delay, verification

Not sure, what I am searching for, may be someone could point me the right direction.
I have to run some part of code after some file has been uploaded to a folder.
That means, a user by clicking Upload button starts `function(1)` that saves file to disk. As long as file is uploaded, starts another `function(2)` that works with this file.

I thought about to bind `function(2)` to Upload button, with some kind of delay or verification, if file is uploaded.

How can it be realized? Which method to use? Any ideas?

Comment: Are function(1) and function(2) PHP functions running on the server, or Javascript functions running in the browser? One thing to consider is that PHP does not start running until after a complete request has been received, which means the file has been uploaded,

Comment: I don't use JS or jQuery, that's not an option. Everything runs on server

Answer (score 0):

Event listeners seem a good use case here.  Once `function(1)` is completed, it can emit a `FileUploaded` event and `function(2)` can be called from a listener registered to the `FileUploaded` event.

Event listeners can also be queued if they are long running tasks as to not force the upload request from waiting until `function(2)` is done before returning a response.

Depending on your use case, you could also just queue a job for `function(2)` at the end of `function(1)`.  Event listeners would allow you to decouple `function(1)` from `function(2)`.

Comment: qeue? you mean this? -> https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues Does this require database ? Besause I don't use any

Comment: If you wanted function(2) to run without delaying the response, yes.  More specifically in the context of my answer: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/events#queued-event-listeners

Comment: Ok, gonna read through, will take some time to answer, thanks.

Comment: `Does this require database ?`  There's multiple queue drivers.  So, no, you don't require a database.